# How do I change the default silkscreen font size in Kicad?

Tags: kicad

I'm trying to place a bunch of small text on the silkscreen in Kicad but I don't see where to change the default size. Where is this setting in Kicad?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With KiCad (ver BZR 4022 Stable), it is easy to achieve this.

Open up your KiCad PCB and go to "**Dimensions » Texts and Drawings**".

[image]

On the *Texts and Drawings* window, you will see two textboxes that allow you to enter default horizontal and vertical sizes for text, as it can be seen in the below screenshot.

Enter your preferred values and click OK.

[image]

Note: These textboxes may include values that has lots of digits after the decimal point. This is because of the KiCad's unit conversion system. If you switch to metric units, you will see these values are normal.

Comment: This seems to have been moved to: File->Board Settings-> Text & Graphics -> Defaults. Also, as of this comment it seems like this only affects when adding new silkscreen text. When I convert from sch->pcb it doesn't seem to take (lmk if anyone finds a way around this)